# Unable to install Nokogiri with dependencies on Redhat Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, libxml2, libxslt

I am using Ruby 1.9.3 and therefore have to use an older version of Nokogiri. I need to install Nokogiri v1.5.10.

Initially I got an error that libxml2 is missing. After installing libxml2 I got the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri-1.5.10.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /opt/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... no
-----
libxslt is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Do I need to install each and every dependency manually?

If so, how do i determine what version to use?

*NOTE*: The server does not have access to the internet. Therefore, I have to `scp` rpm or tar files to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately yes, you will need to install each dependency manually with that version of Nokogiri as I don't believe they packaged the dependencies in until version 1.6.0.rc1.

Comment: how do I determine what version of dependencies to install

Comment: Hmm, I'm not finding a list easily either.  Libxslt-dev (at least that's the Ubuntu variation) is your immediate failed dependency, but I don't know what version you need.